# visual studio 2012 ultimate new dependency graph error

Tags: visual-studio-2012

working with visual studio 2012 ultimate everytime i create a new dependency graph i get this error :

```
Unable to connect to the specified database.

An exception occurred attempting to connect to a database using the following connection string:
Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=;Initial Catalog=master;
Integrated Security=True;Enlist=False;
Asynchronous Processing=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Connect Timeout=30.

Check that the specified SQL Server instance exists and the service is running.
```

my solution get build properly and my connection string is something like this :

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=JewelryStore;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

what is the problem here?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your issue is likely a problem with your localDB instance at:

```
%localappdata%\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\v11.0
```

I had the same problem because when I installed VS12 my computer was not in a domain and I recently joined it to a domain and my user account does not have permissions to the SQL DB.
To fix the issue I ran

```
sqllocaldb stop "v11.0" -k
sqllocaldb delete "v11.0"
sqllocaldb create "v11.0" 
sqllocaldb start "v11.0"
```

I then restarted VS 2012 and my local DB is now usable and the Dependency Graph is now created

Comment: I don't have localDB installed on my computer. is there anyway so that i can use sql server 2008 r2 instead of localDB. my connection string is set appropriately but i still get error.

Comment: Fairly certain it has to use localdb, which I believe is a Pre-req install for VS

Comment: you mean there isn't anyway to use sql server instead of localdb?

Comment: No there does not appear to be that option

Comment: This answer also fixed the same issue I was having with Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.  Uninstall/Reinstall of LocalDB did not work, but these commands got it working.

Comment: The 3rd command fail for me with this: `Creation of LocalDB instance "v11.0" failed because of the following error:
The specified LocalDB version is not available on this computer.` I managed to create a localDB with v12.0 instead but don't know where to change this connection string.

Comment: I needed to install the v11.0 version again. Found [here](https://www.microsoft.com/betaexperience/pd/SQLEXPCTAV2/enus/default.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

After the suggested solution I still had the error.
I had to execute Visual Studio as Administrator, this way solve the problem.