# Visual Studio Code Map: Unable to connect to the specified database

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, code-map

I can't use Code Map in Visual Studio due to this error:

> Unable to connect to the specified database.
>
> An exception occurred attempting to connect to a database using the
>   following connection string:   Data
>   Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=;Initial
>   Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;Enlist=False;Asynchronous
>   Processing=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Connect Timeout=30.
>
> Check that the specified SQL Server instance exists and the service is
>   running.

I've read this questions with the same problem:

[Code Map not working in VS2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105857/code-map-not-working-in-vs2012)

[visual studio 2012 ultimate new dependency graph error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12493221/visual-studio-2012-ultimate-new-dependency-graph-error)

1) I've installed  [SQL Server Data Tools for VS2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj650015)

2) I've updated VS, and re-installed SQL Server component (in a default uninstall/modify/repair menu)

3) Then I successfully stopped and deleted local database (like in 2nd question):

> sqllocaldb stop "v11.0" -k
>
> sqllocaldb delete "v11.0"

But failed to create one:

> sqllocaldb create "v11.0"
>
> Creation of LocalDB instance "v11.0" failed because of the following
>   error:
>
> The specified LocalDB version is not available on this computer.

But creating and starting another version succeeded:

> sqllocaldb create "v12.0"
>
> LocalDB instance "v12.0" created with version 12.0.2000.8.
>
> sqllocaldb start "v12.0"
>
> LocalDB instance "v12.0" started.

Now I'm confused what is actually wrong. After each step I restarted VS and tried to use diagrams - but nothing changed.

How to fix the problem?

Comment: Can you change the connection string to:  Data Source=(LocalDB)\v1**2**.0; etc.?

Comment: I don't know where it is. It is not in `App.config`, this string appears in error text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried changing your database name? You can use something like (Look at your appsettings.json file or web.config file)

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Server=YourDatasource;Database=DatabaseNameAsYouWish;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

If you use SQL Management Studio, you will find the Data Source Connection string while you are connecting to the database. Copy and paste it, then try again. If it works, let me know, please.

**Edit: Setup Connection String for ASP.NET Core 5 Web API Project**

**Step 1:**
For ASP.NET Core 5, in the `appsettings.json` file, put the connection string

```cs
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "sqlConnection": "Server=YourServerName;Database=YourDatabaseName;Integrated Security=true; Trusted_Connection=True;"
  },
```

(Note: If you want to use localdb, the connection string would be

```cs
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "sqlConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=YourDatabaseName;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  },
```

)

**Where to find Server name?**

1. Open SQL Server Management Studio

[image: Server Name]

2. In the Server name field, if you do not see the server name listed, click Browse for more...

[image: Click Browse for more...]

3. Click the + sign next to Database Engine and you will see your Server name. Click on the server name and select it. Now connect to your SQL Server.

[image]

Now connect to your SQL Server.

**Step 2.**
In the `startup.cs` add the service in the `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){ place your sql connectiono service here }` method

```cs
// DatabaseContext comes from DatabaseContext.cs
            services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options => 
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("sqlConnection")) // sqlConnection comes from appSettings connectionString
            );
```

Comment: I've used `App.config` file instead and `connectionString` must be copied from exception text. But the general idea is right, thank you

Answer (score 49):

This worked for me:

Delete, Create, Start localDB instance used by CodeMap:

```
%localappdata%\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\MSSQLLocalDB
```

Using these commands:

```
sqllocaldb stop "MSSQLLocalDB" -k
sqllocaldb delete "MSSQLLocalDB"
sqllocaldb create "MSSQLLocalDB" 
sqllocaldb start "MSSQLLocalDB"
```

Then restart VS

Comment: Working! Thx you bro!

Comment: I received an error when trying to create a new instance, but I noticed one was created when I re-ran code map.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the difference between automatic and named (or private) [LocalDb instances](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh234692.aspx).

The support files necessary for v11.0 (SQL Server 2012) are probably no longer installed on your system. v12.0 indicates SQL Server version 2014.